# Conversion of point grid to a raster with open source tools (Gdal, QGIS ...)

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, gdal, geotools

I'm looking to do something which seem simple to me, but I haven't found a solution since 2 days I looked for.

I've got a Postgis DB with lot of points (WGS84) spaced of 100 meters which cover a territory. For each of these points, I've got a value associated. I want to convert all theses point to a raster Geotiff.

The ideal process will make a Geotiff file where each pixels corresponds to the value of the corresponding points of the db.

I tried the heatmap plug-in of QGIS, but It doesn't do what I want, it interpolate lot of new points I don't need, I want in the tiff file only values I've got in my database.

Any suggestion about how to easily generate this file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Convert the PostGIS layer to a shapefile in QGIS (save-as), then use
   the Vector|Conversion|Rasterize tool;
2. Use the gdal_rasterize command directly.

For the second option:

```
gdal_rasterize -a VAL -ts [x] [y] PG:'host=localhost dbname=DB user=USER'  
  -sql "SELECT the_geom, VAL FROM table" out.tif
```

Where:

- VAL = the value to assign to the raster (same as the VAL in the
  SELECT statement);
- [x] [y] are the X and Y dimensions of the extent of the point table;
- DB and USER are the database and username;
- the_geom and VAL are the geometry and value columns you're interested in from 'table', respectively;
- out.tif is the output TIF file.

Note: the heatmap plugin doesn't *interpolate* values - it uses something like a kernel density algorithm to smooth known values for areas around the measured points.

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot. I think, the possibility of Postgis connexion is not written in the gdal_rasterize manual http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html . Now, I have to find a way a complete pixel where I have got no value.

Comment: I've got some mistake with the -tr option of gdal_rasterize, if you got time to help me, I would be very nice, If not never mind : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92797/make-a-raster-with-pixel-scale-100-by-100-meter-with-gdal-rasterize

Comment: Simbamangu, can I use gdal_rasterize to turn a csv of lat/long (or point shapefile) into a raster, where each cell represents the number of points that are within that cell? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Rasterize tool in QGIS (Raster - Conversion)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the tool works only from shp file. I'll look if QGis can generate this ckind of file.

Comment: Yes QGIS can make a shapefile.  You can load your PostGIS point table into QGIS and save it as a shapefile (right click on the PostGIS layer and choose Save As).